# What is the best way to change the source of an imageview?

Tags: android, imageview

I have one imageview which consist of one png file. I want to change the source of this imageview according to 4 different events (4 different pngs).
Currently I'm changing the source with imageView.setImageResource, but this has lag and causes lots of Choreographer warnings.
Are there better ways?

Comment: Can you post your current code ?

Comment: You are doing your work on UIThread and without any animation. Post your code and try to improve those two points.

Comment: use an image loader library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have four ImageViews on top of each other and then just change the visibility depending on what you want to show. There would be no lag in terms of loading picture to memory because they are all there already. Just make sure that the pictures aren't too memory intensive

Code:

```
if (something)
    imageview1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
else if (something)
    imageview2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

RelativeLayout by default stacks views on top of each other. Setting visibility.gone in linearlayout might also make the views "stack".
XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pic1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp" 
        android:src="@drawable/pic1"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:contentDescription="default picture"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pic2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/pic2"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:contentDescription="pic2"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pic3"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/pic3"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:contentDescription="pic3"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pic4"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/pic4"
        android:visibility="invisible"
    android:contentDescription="pic4"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this library http://square.github.io/picasso/ to load image

Answer (score 1):

Use a library like Picasso or Glide.
They both have a very easy syntax and will load the image in a seperate thread and so no lag happens on the UI thread.

check out the libraries at

https://github.com/bumptech/glide

https://github.com/square/picasso

there are more image loading libraries but these are probably the easiest to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can have 4 imageViews instead of one, that have already loaded your 4 images, and adjust the visibility of these imageViews related to which image must be visible.

Like this, you won't need to change the source of any imageView during execution (just the visibility) and will get rid of the loading/decoding time.

Comment: But you will use more ram.